# Jquery id selector with string "#" as id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to do some jquery fonction on `onclick` event on one link with id `"1_#FF0000"`.

When i use jquery `id` *selector* like

```
$("#1_#FF0000")
```

it is not selecting my link

can any one suggest me how to use jquery selector in this type of case

Comment: your id is starting with number .. ?

Comment: you shouldn't start ID with number even it is HTML5 valid

Comment: its better to use class in your context

Comment: *ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").* From the [w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html)

Comment: @h2ooooooo this is no more the case in HTML5, but still in CSS and just better to not use a number at the beginning of an attribute ID

Comment: ..and simply to add a manual entry for what @A.Wolff mentioned: [specification for ID tag in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Here's a [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) discussing this.

Comment: @patel.milanb - Why a class? OP wants to identify a specific element, which is exactly what the id attribute is for.

Comment: @nnnnnn: agree. BUT using ID(starting with number, includes #) why not give it a specific class and use it.. and stay up-to-date with HTML specification

Comment: @patel.milanb I'm agree, i think OP would better to use classes instead of IDs because i guess he has more than one element for red (#FF0000) and other color

Comment: @A.Wolff: couldnt agree more.. i also think he has list of colors on his page..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way

```
$("[id^=1_#FF0000]")
```

OR

```
 $("[id='1_#FF0000']")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pBYgs/11/)

Reference

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: @SomnathKharat check fiddle demo it s working with and without also

Comment: Why using 'Start with' statement? Why not just: `$("[id=1_#FF0000]")` ?

Answer (score 7):

you need to escape it using `\#`

```
$("#1_\\#FF0000")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
$("[id='1_#FF0000']")
```

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

`ID` must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[**HTML Specification**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute)